# Calculating duration of a loan

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I calculate the number of periods of a loan given the starting balance, the annual percentage rate, and the monthly payment amount?

I know how to calculate the monthly payment amount given the first two, plus the number of periods.

Comment: You solve the same equation for the number of periods.  It involves taking a logarithm because the number of periods is in an exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B = \sum_\limits {i=1}^n \frac {CF_i}{(1+r)^n}$ is your NPV calculation.  The NPV of the future cash flows equals the loan balance.

When the cash flows are uniform, the expression can be simplified to:
$B = P \frac {(1+r)((1+r)^n-1)}{r}$
Now solve for $n.$

$1+\frac {Br}{P(1+r)} = (1+r)^n\\
\dfrac {\log \left(1+\frac {Br}{P(1+r)} \right)}{\log (1+r)} = n$

Comment: Thanks. I think I derived the same formula, only not as far simplified.